# VPN inside virtual machine in mac

Tags: mac, vpn, vmware-fusion, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have a Mac book pro running mountain lion and I have vmware fusion installed. I have RHEL 6.0 64 bit vm running (in NAT mode) and pptp is installed in rhel. I tried connecting my office vpn but it fails. Here is the log

```
Oct 17 09:00:32 rhel6 NetworkManager[1561]: <info> Starting VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp'...
Oct 17 09:00:32 rhel6 NetworkManager[1561]: <info> VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 2777
Oct 17 09:00:32 rhel6 NetworkManager[1561]: <info> VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp' appeared, activating connections
Oct 17 09:00:32 rhel6 NetworkManager[1561]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 1
Oct 17 09:00:32 rhel6 NetworkManager[1561]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 3
Oct 17 09:00:32 rhel6 NetworkManager[1561]: <info> VPN connection 'OFFICEVPN' (Connect) reply received.
Oct 17 09:00:32 rhel6 pppd[2780]: Warning: can't open options file /root/.ppprc: Permission denied
Oct 17 09:00:32 rhel6 pppd[2780]: Plugin /usr/lib64/pppd/2.4.5/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Oct 17 09:00:32 rhel6 pppd[2780]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Oct 17 09:00:32 rhel6 pppd[2780]: Using interface ppp0
Oct 17 09:00:32 rhel6 pppd[2780]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/2
Oct 17 09:00:32 rhel6 pptp[2781]: nm-pptp-service-2777 log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Oct 17 09:00:32 rhel6 pptp[2789]: nm-pptp-service-2777 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
Oct 17 09:00:32 rhel6 pptp[2789]: nm-pptp-service-2777 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:739]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
Oct 17 09:00:32 rhel6 pptp[2789]: nm-pptp-service-2777 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:773]: Client connection established.
Oct 17 09:00:33 rhel6 pptp[2789]: nm-pptp-service-2777 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
Oct 17 09:00:33 rhel6 pptp[2789]: nm-pptp-service-2777 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:858]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
Oct 17 09:00:33 rhel6 pptp[2789]: nm-pptp-service-2777 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:897]: Outgoing call established (call ID 0, peer's call ID 58544).
Oct 17 09:01:03 rhel6 pppd[2780]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Oct 17 09:01:03 rhel6 NetworkManager[1561]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Oct 17 09:01:03 rhel6 pppd[2780]: Connection terminated.
Oct 17 09:01:03 rhel6 pppd[2780]: Modem hangup
Oct 17 09:01:03 rhel6 pptp[2781]: nm-pptp-service-2777 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:204]: short read (-1): Input/output error
Oct 17 09:01:03 rhel6 pptp[2781]: nm-pptp-service-2777 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:216]: pppd may have shutdown, see pppd log
Oct 17 09:01:03 rhel6 pptp[2789]: nm-pptp-service-2777 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:234]: Closing connection (unhandled)
Oct 17 09:01:03 rhel6 pptp[2789]: nm-pptp-service-2777 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
Oct 17 09:01:03 rhel6 pptp[2789]: nm-pptp-service-2777 log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:79]: Closing connection (call state)
Oct 17 09:01:03 rhel6 pppd[2780]: Exit.
Oct 17 09:01:03 rhel6 NetworkManager[1561]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Oct 17 09:01:03 rhel6 NetworkManager[1561]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Oct 17 09:01:03 rhel6 NetworkManager[1561]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 6
Oct 17 09:01:03 rhel6 NetworkManager[1561]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Oct 17 09:01:03 rhel6 NetworkManager[1561]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Oct 17 09:01:03 rhel6 NetworkManager[1561]: <info> Policy set 'Auto eth5' (eth5) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
```

Can someone help in this regard.

Comment: hi, can you pass more information about your problem....???

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I've got into it recently, thanks.